# Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.Extensions.Options.IOptions

Tags: c#, asp.net

System.InvalidOperationException
HResult=0x80131509
Message=Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.Extensions.Options.IOptions`1[Web.Extensions.WebSettings]' while attempting to activate 'Web.Startup'.
Source=Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions

This happened when I migrated asp.net core 2.1 to 3.1. Any assistance will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: How are you building your DI container to be able to resolve `IOption<T>`?

Comment: What is `Web.Extensions.WebSettings`? How do you register and resolve it/

Comment: @GuruStron am getting that error in Program.cs main when i run my application. I migrated from asp.net core 2.1 to 3.1.

Comment: @Richard getting that error when I run my asp.net core 3.1(migrated from 2.1). The error is in program.cs main. You can share any update i may be missing if you know, for DI container that resolves IOption<T>

Comment: @KorirCornelius this does not answer neither mine not Richards question. Please check [ask] and provide a [mre].

Comment: In general you should register options via `Configure` call - `services.Configure<Web.Extensions.WebSettings>(...)`

Comment: did you miss something in your program.cs? maybe this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48069829/unable-to-resolve-service-for-type-ioptionsdataaccessconfiguration-in-non-asp) works